# Identify salvaged parts

Tags: relay, components

I took apart an old printer and found two components that look like relays.

[image]

But they have no markings of any kind, save for a small sticker each that I think may be serial numbers.

They are 4335xit3 and 5345xft4.

I would love to find some data sheets to know what they can do, but I don't know how to identify them without markings.

Comment: fyi: [General discussion about merit of salvaging parts from consumer goods.](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/87190/7036)

Comment: While theoretically possible, relays are not common in printers - generally the electro-mechanical components have more to do with the fact the a printer is a type of enclosed robot.  If you want to understand what these do, you should consider where they were in the physical assembly.  A mechanical actuator that closed a circuit as well as doing something physical would be more likely to be found than a pure relay in the sense of a mechanical actuator that had not purpose other than to close a circuit.  It would also be good to state the type of printer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is the flyback transformer used to generate the high voltage charge in a laser printer.

The comparable circuits in a CRT-based television can remain hazardous for substantial time after power is removed, unless the tube capacitance is carefully drained by someone knowledgeable in the appropriate procedure.

I can't tell you off the top of my head what associated capacitance would be found in a laser printer or what voltage it would charge to, but until you know for certain, you probably don't want to be working on or disassembling the machine - if something is still charged the results could range from surprising through painful to truly hazardous, **even when unplugged from the wall**.  Such hazards are not necessarily confined to televisions or large objects - in childhood I got a rather unique burn from discharging the capacitor in a small camera flash through my finger.

Comment: Hmm, OK. I was hoping to recycle and save some money, but I see that it's probably better to just buy from a reputable source with the data sheets.

Comment: Even before lack of data (which can often be overcome with experience), there's the eternal problem of needing what you find or finding what you need.

Comment: I've seen an almost identical device in a laser printer, it was providing charge to the toner drum so it's most definitely a HV flyback (3-5kV probably)