# Is this capacitor polarized?

Tags: capacitor, identification, polarity

I recovered a few capacitors of this style from an old cassette player. As far as I can tell, it seems like Mylar film, but the “100⊖” marking has me wondering. Is this some peculiar shaped tantalum capacitor, or is the indicator not a polarity marking?

[image]

Comment: [related thread](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/87190/7036) about salvaging components from junk

Comment: Given neither end has any markings to indicate polarity, no broad lines coming down an end, I'd say this is 0.010uF 100Volt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess would be 10 nF mylar (first 2 digits = 10, third = multiplier 10^3 pF) 100 V. J = 5 %. I reckon that 10 nF is too small for a tantalum so I don't think this is polarized.

Comment: Me, too.  I have no clue what the dingus is after the 100 - maybe a really little logo?  But it's the right size and shape to be a mylar cap with that value.